# Restler 3 Custom Routing

Tags: php, restler

I have been searching for an example of creating manual/custom routes in Restler 3 to achieve a URL like this.

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/solution/categories/{category-id}/folders/{folder-id}/articles/{article-id}.json
```

I would like everything handled by the Solution class.  I would like a seperate method for each get().  Is this possible?

```php
Defaults::$useUrlBasedVersioning = true;
$r = new Restler();
$r->setSupportedFormats('JsonFormat', 'XmlFormat');
$r->setAPIVersion(1);
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources');
$r->addAPIClass('Solution');
$r->addAuthenticationClass('AccessControl');
$r->handle();
```

I have experimented with the Routing examples with no luck thus far.

http://restler3.luracast.com/examples/_006_routing/readme.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example

```
<?php

class Solution
{

    /**
     * @url GET categories/{category_id}/folders/{folder_id}/articles/{article_id}
     */
    public function categories($category_id, $folder_id, $article_id)
    {
        return func_get_args();
    }

}
```

Comment: Truly amazing how well designed Restler is.  I am very grateful.